# Не могу редактировать код laravel sail через phpStorm

Tags: laravel, docker, phpstorm

Всем привет. Недавно начали разработку нового проекта и решили использовать для него laravel + docker, нашел, что у Ларки есть уже встроенная возможность в виде laravel sail, поднял проект, однако теперь не могу понять, как мне открыть его через phpStorm. Пытался подключиться по ssh, но получал такую ошибку WARN  172.21.0.1:35172 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF).
Буду так же благодарен, если сразу скажете, какие могут быть подводные камни при выгрузке этого проекта на гит и накатывании на него React